# Handling Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, multithreading, stored-procedures

I am developing a console application. After doing the initial checks and pre requisites, i have to introduce 5 threads based on the sql table's rows. say for example, if my table consist of 1000 rows, then i will have to split up the rows and assign equally to all 5 threads, where in this case, i will do the split and assign (creating a datatable) 200 rows to each thread and then all 5 threads would call the SP at the same time with the datatable. Is there any thing to be handled in the SP, since it is going to get executed parallely by 5 threads and how can i handle the insert, delete and truncates inside the SP? will it be a problem, if more than one insert or delete or truncate queries executed at the same time, is there any collision occurs? or is there any lock functionality in SP to allow only one operation for a sql statement in SP?

As i am new to this to kind of requirement, i need help in finding out the problems which is occurs possibly and way to overcome it. it would be great if i get any tips and tricks to follow in this kind of scenario..

Thanks in advance..

abivenkat

Comment: Can you show what the procedure does?

Comment: Can you explain WHY you want to use 5 threads to query the table? This seems like a really strange requirement. I would have expected maybe 1 thread to call the sproc and possibly multiple threads to process the output, but this seems odd.

Comment: i have never seen a stored procedure that does any thread handling. all the concurrency issues are managed by the app server. obviously when one process is executing a SP, i think the other processes have to wait on this process to complete the job because a SP is an atomic transaction n i cannot see how 2 threads from the same application or even otherwise would be executing a SP without a lock on it except if it is managed by the DB Server process itself of course.

Comment: SWeko:It will calculate the books left out in a book shop after a days sale, it will inserts, deletes and truncates. used temp tables in the SP to loop through and find the numbers.

Comment: Daniel:reason y i am using 5 threads is to make the process quicker and split the records and perform parallely, which will be quick in time. for ex, if ther are 1000 rows, each thread will process 200 rows parallely or if i use single thread, it will alone process all 1000 rows and process will be slow.

Comment: @VenkatramananLakshmanan ..you should know that what you've just said isn't always the case. This sounds like premature optimisation to me..

Comment: @VenkatramananLakshmanan Have you actually proved that theory. Are you claiming that 10 threads would be quicker than 5? Like I said, I understand if you get the data with 1 thread and then process the results using multiple threads. However, I believe you are guessing that 5 queries will be faster. Just think about it - it makes no sense.

Comment: 5 guys cooking 5 meals on 1 stove is faster if they use it sequentially.

Comment: im not really sure but if we benchmark a single threaded application against a multi threaded application, there will be many instances where the uni threaded application will emerge winner because having poorly executed threading can really take u down a notch. but yet i think this question is intriguing n challenging not because of if it can be done but also because if it can actually slow things down if it was not done.. but it should be posted in threading and im sure lots more would suggest a befitting solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ISOLATION LEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259216%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) setting in SQL Server. It should preferably be set as high as possible to prevent data corruption, however, that can and will result in lots of locks, and doing thing in parallel might make the matters worse, rather than better.

Depending on the code of your procedure you might even get deadlocks, that will just rollback some calls, that should be re-issued, that could cause additional deadlocks, and before you know it, your database is in a totally fubar'd state.

What I would recommend for such data intensive operations, is to not paralelyze them at all, just run them one by one. If your server is a multicore machine, it might even paralelyze things on it's own.

Of course, these are broad hand waves. To get specific information, the structure of the data (along with any indexes) as well as the code that will be executed need to be analyzed.